# Monitor progress of executable so it can be reported on webform

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, fortran, legacy-code

I've recently been looking into taking a legacy building analysis program and giving it a front end with asp.NET Webforms and javascript.  (The legacy code is written in Fortran with the intent that it would be run on the web server or another remote machine.)

Question: Is it possible to monitor the process of an executable (running on a web server or elsewhere) so that it can be reported on a Webform?

The legacy code is still part of an ongoing development program.  We're not looking to re-code it into C#, etc. since:

1) performance is paramount; and

2) it would be a mammoth undertaking.

But the Fortran code can be modified to output something or call something to update progress and let the user know (hopefully, by way of a Webform) how the executable is doing.

Has anyone come across or applied a programming model that would provide this feature?

Comment: search term "progress for long running process in WebForms/ASP.Net"... Like http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/vb-net/executing-long-running-tasks-with-the-progress-bar-in-asp-net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make something like a progress bar that doesn't affect the performance of your code, you can do something like this.

1. Create global variables in a module

   ```
   module progress
     implicit none
     real*8           :: progress_value    = huge(1.d0)
     integer          :: progress_bar(2)   = (/ 1, 1 /)
     integer          :: progress_refresh  = 2
     integer          :: progress_unit     = 66
     logical          :: progress_active   = .False.
     character*(64)   :: progress_title    = "UNDEFINED"
     character*(128)  :: progress_filename = "/tmp/progress"
   end module
   ```

   - `progress_value` : A value you want to monitor (like a running average for instance)
   - `progress_bar` : the 1st index will contain the current loop count, and the 2nd index the total loop count. The ratio `dble(progress_bar(1))/dble(progress_bar(2))` will give you the current percentage of progress.
   - `progress refresh` : A time interval in seconds between each refresh
   - `progress_unit` : A unit number for the file in which you will write the info
   - `progress_active` : `.True.` when you are monitoring, `.False.` otherwise.
   - `progress_title` : Lets you identify what you are monitoring.
   - `progress_filename` : Name of the file in which you will store the progress
2. Create routines to start/stop the monitoring

   Initialize the monitoring:

   ```
   subroutine start_progress(max,title,progress_init)
     use progress
     implicit none
     integer, intent(in)       :: max
     character*(*), intent(in) :: title
     real*8, intent(in)        :: progress_init

     progress_bar(1) = 0
     progress_bar(2) = max
     progress_title = title
     progress_active = .True.
     progress_value = progress_init
     call run_progress()
   end
   ```

   - `max` : Max value of the loop count
   - `title` : Title of what you monitor
   - `progress_init` : Initial value of the `progress_value`

   Terminate the monitoring:

   ```
   subroutine stop_progress()
     use progress
     implicit none
     progress_active = .False.
     call write_progress()
   end
   ```
3. A subroutine to print the data in the progress file

   ```
   subroutine write_progress()
     use progress
     implicit none
     open(unit=progress_unit,file=progress_filename)
     write(progress_unit,'(A)') progress_title
     write(progress_unit,'(F5.1,X,A)') dble(100*progress_bar(1))/dble(progress_bar(2)), '%'
     write(progress_unit,*) progress_value
     close(unit=progress_unit)
   end
   ```
4. And the core which uses the `ALARM` signal

   ```
   recursive subroutine run_progress()
     use progress
     implicit none
     call write_progress()
     if (progress_active) then
       call alarm(progress_refresh,run_progress)
     endif
   end
   ```
5. This is how you use it:

   ```
   program test
     use progress
     implicit none

     integer :: i
     integer, parameter :: nmax = 10

     double precision :: s

   ! --> Before the loop, run start_progress
     s = 0.d0
     call start_progress(nmax, "Dummy loop", s)
     do i=1,nmax
       call sleep(1)
       s = s+1.d0

   ! --> Update the global variables at the end of each loop cycle
   !     (there is no function call, so it is almost free)

       progress_value  = s
       progress_bar(1) = i
     enddo

   ! --> After the loop, call stop_progress
     call stop_progress()
   end
   ```

If you don't want to use files but named pipes instead (without the open/close statements in the writing routine),
it may not work well with Fortran because of its buffered output. You can try

```
    export GFORTRAN_UNBUFFERED_ALL=1
```

in your shell to change this.

You can get the code here : https://gist.github.com/scemama/9977dc1290685b541f9c

Comment: Hi Anthony,  Wow!  That's a fantastic example coupled with an incredibly comprehensive explanation.  I'll have a go at implementing your suggestion.  Thank you so much for taking the time to respond.

Comment: I'm not sure `alarm` is a good choice to do that... I could find anything for `gfortran` but the [documentation for `ifort`](http://www.complexfluids.ethz.ch/MK/ifort.pdf) is a little disheartening on that subject: *The calling program then suspends and calls proc, which runs in another thread*. The main loop is paused while writing the status! It gets worse when running multiple threads: *The thread that
proc runs in has a higher priority than any other thread in the process. All other threads are essentially suspended until proc terminates*. Not a good idea at all...

Comment: I have never observed any noticeable performance degradation with this, even with OpenMP. If an I/O takes  ~10 milliseconds and if the interval is set to 1 second, this corresponds only to a 1% performance loss. I agree that it is not a good path to take if the time you spend writing the file is comparable to the interval. On the example I posted (5 file writes in 10 seconds), the wall time changes from 10.005s to 10.006s.

Answer (score 1):

The FORTRAN program can write the status (say started on 25/02/2015 12:05:57, completed on 25/02/2015 12:08:38) onto a text file or database table. On the status web page you can use auto refresh or jQuery ajax call to check the status of the process and update it.

Comment: I like the idea of a text file - nice and simple.  But what if while my Web App has the file open to get status information and the Fortran code wants to write to the file - could there be problems with this?

Comment: The web app can open the file in read only mode, therefore it should not lock it for editing.

Answer (score 1):

I find the easiest way to do I/O in Fortran is using its native .dat-file-format. It's binary, but it's a relatively sane format that allows multiple records with any kind of array data to be stored. To get an idea on how to deal with these kinds of files outside of Fortran context, you can have a look at the `unpackNextRecord` function in the [following python script](https://github.com/muellermichel/Hybrid-Fortran/blob/master/hf_bin/accuracy.py). This should be relatively easy to translate into any language (in case it doesn't already exist there).

Now, on Fortran side you can create these files by using a function like

```
subroutine writeToFile[MyDataType](path, array) 
  implicit none 
  [MyDataType], intent(in), dimension(:) :: array 
  character(len=*), intent(in) :: path 
  character(len=:), allocatable :: dirname 
  integer(4) :: imt 

  dirname = getDirectory(path) 
  call makeDirectory(dirname) 
  call findNewFileHandle(imt) 
  open(imt, file = path, form = 'unformatted', status = 'replace') 
  write(imt) array 
  close(imt) 
  deallocate(dirname) 
end subroutine
```

You can also write to a file handle multiple times with different data types this way, say if you have some string and an array of numbers you'd like to save - just add more `write(imt)` calls and inputs to your helper subroutine. To get the helper functions `makeDirectory` and `findNewFileHandle` that are used here, see [the following Fortran 90 module](https://github.com/muellermichel/Hybrid-Fortran/blob/master/hf_lib/helper_functions.F90).

This stuff might feel odd if you're used to dealing with text files, but in Fortran it's safer and more comfortable this way - if you want to write plain text, you'll stumble quite a bit until you get it right, let me tell you.

Comment: This could work.  Do you think there would be any issues with accessing the output file while it's being written (by the Fortran executable)?  Why I ask is that I see occasion where the Web App doing the monitoring might open the file for status information at the same time the Fortran executable wants to write to it (to update that information).  Do you see this being an problem?  (The big thing is that the Fortran code cannot be interrupted or made to wait should the file be locked for reading.)

Comment: And I'd like to +1 your suggestion but I'm waiting to acquire enough votes myself to enable this.

Comment: Locking the file is an interesting problem, I haven't yet thought about this. This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18868922/fortran-wait-to-open-a-file-until-closed-by-another-application) seems to be relevant. Also [this post](http://computer-programming-forum.com/49-fortran/b40aad24e552b0b7.htm). I'd avise against using the `share` keyword in `open`, since it doesn't seem to be well supported.

Comment: One shortcut I could think of: Use the current date in the filename (I'd make sure to use UTC both in the reader and the writer) and check on the reader side to not read in something that has been created too recently (time offset depends on how much data you want to write and how busy your server's disks are). To my knowledge there shouldn't be a problem on Fortran side if you simply try to read a currently opened file without changing it, so the only problem seems to be that Fortran might not be done yet when you start reading - which above solution would avoid.

Answer (score 1):

My preference for calling long running Fortran routines from C# is to compile the Fortran routine as a DLL and pass a callback function from C# into the Fortran routine. The advantage here is that you don't have multiple process contending for simultaneous access to the same file.

```
module MyLib

    implicit none

    interface
        subroutine ProgressUpdateAction(percentProgress)
            integer, intent(in) :: percentProgress
        end subroutine
    end interface   

contains

    subroutine DoWork(progressUpdate)

        !DIR$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT :: DoWork
        !DIR$ ATTRIBUTES ALIAS: 'DoWork' :: DoWork
        !DIR$ ATTRIBUTES REFERENCE :: progressCallBack

        procedure(ProgressUpdateAction), intent(in), pointer :: progressUpdate

        integer, parameter :: STEP_COUNT = 9
        integer :: i, percentProgress

        do i = 1, STEP_COUNT

            ! Update the status.
            percentProgress = (i - 1) * 100.0 / STEP_COUNT
            call progressUpdate(percentProgress)

            ! Do something expensive...

        end do

    end subroutine

end module
```

In the C# calling routine create a matching delegate. Remember to pass everything by reference - the Fortran default.

```
public static class FortranLib
{
    private const string _dllName = "FortranLib.dll";

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public delegate void ProgressUpdateAction(ref int progress); // Important the int is passed by ref (else we could use built-in Action<T> instead of delegate).

    [DllImport(_dllName, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern void DoWork([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)] ref ProgressUpdateAction progressUpdate);
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            FortranLib.ProgressUpdateAction updateProgress = delegate(ref int p)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Progress: " + p + "%");
            };

            FortranLib.DoWork(ref updateProgress);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Full details here: http://www.luckingtechnotes.com/calling-fortran-from-c-monitoring-progress-using-callbacks/

Comment: I whole-heartedly agree.  I think the way moving forward is to .DLL the .EXE.  Parts of the project have been compiled from static libraries and we're in the process of converting these to shared.  (This is a bit of a stepping stone.  The end game is to have the number crunching done on Linux boxes since they are significantly cheaper on services like AWS ... the movement of data is a little more involved.  We'll leave that for another question.)  Thanks for your suggestion.